# Laravel dynamic post title in navbar-browser

Tags: laravel

Post not displaying title in Laravel new version

It's showing. ZumOos - `<?php echo e($post->title); ?>`

How to solve this problem?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m5hS.png]

Answer (score 0):

```
<title>ZumOos - <?php echo $post->title; ?></title>
```

Comment: @ParasRaiyani: You mention your edit, but it still doesn't provide a brief description, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using it in a Blade Template, you can use {{ }} to get PHP variables echoed.
I would use:

```
<title>ZumOos - {{ $post->title }}</title>
```